# How do I apply FFT on a 3D Array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D array that has the shape (features, timestep, samples). I would like to apply the numpy fft function on each feature for the length of timestep for each sample. I have this, but I am uncertain whether this is the best way or whether there needs to be a loop to iterate through each sample.

```
import numpy as np
x_train_fft = np.fft.fft(x_train, axis=0) #selected axis 0 as this is the axis of features
```

Comment: Could you reformulate your question better, please? you could put input and expected output as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was the way to do it

```
X_transform_FFT =[]
for i in range(x_train.shape[0]):
    f  = abs(np.fft.fft(x_train[i, :, :], axis = 1))
    X_transform_FFT.append(f)
    np.asarray(X_transform_FFT)
print(X_transform_FFT)
```